# Spring RestTemplate Post to Salesforce Bad request 400

Tags: java, spring, rest, salesforce, postman

Still cracking my brain after having made several calls to retrieve Token and Product, posting a Product was almost impossible with restTemplate even though it succeeded using Postman REST client.

```
public AddProductResponse createProduct(@NonNull AuthenticationTokenResponse authenticationTokenResponse)
{
    String url = authenticationTokenResponse.getInstance_url() + "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Product2";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    //headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationTokenResponse.getAccess_token());
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationTokenResponse.getAccess_token());


    MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestBody.add("Name", "Product Name");
    requestBody.add("product_Reference__c", "SOMERef");

    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    try
    {
        ResponseEntity<AddProductResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, AddProductResponse.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.debug("Error creating product");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I wonder why my postman call succeeded but not with Spring RestTemplate.
POstman screenshot.
[image]

```
postman body.

{"Name" : "My New Prod ",
"product_Reference__c": "REFAKINTEST3"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use *headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));* ? It is commected out in your posted code

Comment: Take alook into serer logfiles, maybe there are some information which helps you

Comment: I did use this, but it made no difference, still bad request. @Jens

Comment: You are sure the request body is correct?

Comment: @Jens, yes, I used the same request body on Postman and it worked, I also used MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(); in a similar other function to get Token information, also worked.

Comment: Please add what you are sending with Postman to youre question.

Comment: Your postman request is not the same as the spring, because `{"Name" : "My New Prod ", "product": "REFAKINTEST3"}` != `{"Name" : "Product Name",
"product_Reference__c": "SOMERef"}`

Comment: @Jens They are equal, I just redacted the second field's name as it contains the name of the company I am working for, but I can make them appear the same.

Comment: @Motolola before your last edit also the second key was different!

Comment: Also the url is not the same, in postman the url ends with shlash in your spring example not

Comment: @Jens I have used many variations of the url while trying to solve the issue, slash and no slash, trust me those information are the same, a wrong url will give 404 ... the difference is that I redacted my company's name from it. The problem will be on the code structure. wrong fields will return a different error with error code.